# Can't enable the PHP DOM extension

Tags: php, unix, php.ini

I have a server that has PHP 7.4.3 installed, but it doesn't load PHP-DOM.

It's not listed in `php -m` or `php -i`, nor when I load PHP on a page.

Here's what I tried so far:

1. Ran `sudo apt-get install php-xml` several times, it installs without a problem and shows the newest version is already installed.
2. Ran `sudo apt-get install php7.4-xml`, it's unable to locate the package.
3. Added `extension=dom.so` to php.ini and checked for the `--disable-dom` flag (not found).
4. Restarted apache multiple times throughout this process.

How can I enable the PHP DOM extension?